Order Matrix Block in Control Panel by Date Field
Is it possible for the individual entries within a matrix field in the Control Panel to appear in the order of a date field?
I have found here information on how the entries are sorted after saving the entry. However, I would like to put them in the correct order directly after creation.
Reordering Matrix blocks by date in the control panel when saving an entry
